# How to identify multiple buttons ID/value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton'
>   to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

I have multiple button which function differently.. the following is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
     <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidInterval" />
     <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidLockerID" />
     <div style="width: 17%; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
          <button type="button" id="bInterval3Hours" text="3Hours" runat="server" onserverclick="bIntervalHours_Click" onclick="showPreloader();"  class="btn btn-default btn-package" style="
                    height: 80px; width: 120px; margin-right: 6px;"><div style="line-height: 18px; text-transform: none;"><span style="font-size: 23px;">3</span><br />Hours</div></button>
          <button type="button" id="bInterval6Hours" text="6Hours" runat="server" onserverclick="bIntervalHours_Click" onclick="showPreloader();" class="btn btn-default btn-package" style="
                    height: 80px; width: 120px; margin-right: 6px;"><div style="line-height: 18px; text-transform: none;"><span style="font-size: 23px;">6</span><br />Hours</div></button>
          <button type="button" id="bInterval12Hours" text="12Hours" runat="server" onserverclick="bIntervalHours_Click" onclick="showPreloader();" class="btn btn-default btn-package" style="
                    height: 80px; width: 120px; margin-right: 6px;"><div style="line-height: 18px; text-transform: none;"><span style="font-size: 23px;">12</span><br />Hours</div></button>
          <button type="button" id="bInterval24Hours" text="24Hours" runat="server" onserverclick="bIntervalHours_Click" onclick="showPreloader();" class="btn btn-default btn-package" style="
                    height: 80px; width: 120px; margin-right: 6px;"><div style="line-height: 18px; text-transform: none;"><span style="font-size: 23px;">24</span><br />Hours</div></button>
     </div>
</div>
```

and the following are the function code

```
 protected void bIntervalHours_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool addLocker = false;
    string itemID = string.Empty;
    string itemCode = string.Empty;
    string itemPrice = string.Empty;

    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    string value = clickedButton.Text;

    setupDB();

    switch (value)
    {
        case "3Hours":
            // 3 hours rental
            // operation for 3 hours
            break;
        case "6Hours":
            // 6 hours rental
            // operation for 6 hours
            break;
        case "12Hours":
            // 12 hours rental
            // operation for 12 hours
            break;
        case "24Hours":
            // 24 hours rental
            // operation for 24 hours
            break;
    }

    .....
    .....

    disposeDB();
}
```

Comment: The error is clear... You are casting wrong. Use `HtmlButton clickedButton = (HtmlButton)sender;`

Comment: @VDWWD Owh ok.. i use the HtmlButton and assign the ID instead of text.. thanks..

Comment: There is a difference between `asp:Button` which are webform controls, and `<input type=button runat=server` which are html controls that are accessible in code behind. The same goes for input type=text or asp:TextBox etc.

Comment: so if i use asp:button then i can use Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;?

Comment: Yep, thats right. But you can still use `HtmlButton` if you wanted to. Just make sure you cast the sender right.